# PHP - Unable to Link Child to Parent

Tags: php, parent-child

I'm trying to link the shop class with the dbh class. It works when they're all in one file, but when I create separate files and try to link them, I get an error saying:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Dbh" not found in C:\wamp64\www\LFDB Final\shop.class.php on line 3
( ! ) Error: Class "Dbh" not found in C:\wamp64\www\LFDB Final\shop.class.php on line 3

Both files are in the LFDB Final folder. Here is the dbh class:

```
<?php
class Dbh {

private $servername;
private $username;
private $password;
private $dbname;
private $charset;

public function connect() {
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "lolita_fashion";
    $this->charset = "utf8mb4";
    
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    } 

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection Failed: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    
    
 }
}
?>
```

Here is the shops class:

```
<?php

class shops extends Dbh {

public function getallshops($limit = "100 PERCENT", $order_col = "-9", $order_type = "DESC") 
{
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query("select distinct
     shops.shop_name, 
     shop_type.shop_type, 
     shop_style.shop_style, 
     shops.link 
     from shops 
     join shop_type on shop_type.id = shops.shop_type 
     join shop_style on shop_style.id = shops.shop_style 
     order by shops.id ASC;
    ");


    $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;

    }
}
?>
```

I've tried adding "includes 'dbh.class.php';" but that works, but I'm following along with my professor and she doesn't use it, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What you're looking for is [autoloading and namespaces](https://opensource.com/article/23/4/autoloading-namespaces-php). That's just one link, there are many.